# Addition of timestamp is not working in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

```
select CAST(current_date as timestamp) 
         + to_char(timestamp '2019-07-08 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::TIMESTAMP;
```

**Current output:** `2019-08-02 00:00:002019-07-08 09:00:00`

Comment: You can't add two timestamps. You can add an interval to a timestamp or subtract two timestamps. What result do you expect from that?

Comment: Unrelated but: `to_char(timestamp '2019-07-08 09:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')::TIMESTAMP;` should only be `timestamp '2019-07-08 09:00:00'`

Comment: Actually I'm trying to add times so the expected output would be time only. It would be great if you can guide me the alternate option. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to add times, then why are you adding timestamps? Try `select current_time + time '09:00:00'`

Comment: when we say current_time it's coming with timezone. Because of that may be time addition(select current_time + time '09:00:00') is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [DATEADD()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) function or the [INTERVAL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_interval_literals.html) syntax to add specific units of time to another date/timestamp.

```
SELECT DATEADD(hour, 9, current_date);
--       date_add
-- ---------------------
--  2019-08-05 09:00:00

SELECT current_date + INTERVAL '9 hours';
--       ?column?
-- ---------------------
--  2019-08-05 09:00:00
```